# E-mail Marketing

Tags: css, html5, css-border

Estou iniciando um código de e-mail marketing, desejo aplicar a peça inteira um `border-left` e um `border-right` de 4px na cor `#b21331`, mas como o código para e-mail marketing não pode conter muitas tags, inclusive a de `style=""` preciso saber uma maneira de conseguir inserir esta borda inline.

Segue meu código atual, se alguém souber como ajudar. Muito Obrigado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>E-mail Marketing</title>
</head>

<body >

<table width="630" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" >

 <tr>
    <td height="43"><table width="630" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="157" height="43">
        <a border="0" href="#" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" src="../img/aberto_r1_c1.jpg" alt="#" width="196" height="43" border="0" style="display:block" title="img1" /></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </td>
 </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta inserir uma tabela dentro da outra, e trocar as cores de fundo, para simular a borda:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>E-mail Marketing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="630" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  bgcolor="#b21331">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <table width="622" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tr><td>
            CABECALHO
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br>
            Aqui vai o conteudo
            <br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            RODAPE
        </td></tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Não usei seu HTML na íntegra como base, pois as tags TR e TD estão com aninhamento meio estranho, mas é fácil você adaptar o exemplo.

Pra mail marketing creio que compensa ter por base o HTML 4 tradicional em vez de XHTML.

Comment: Show, muito Obrigado!!